# Exclude some store from all stores

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, websites, website-restriction

I get all stores by website but i want to exclude someone, his ID is=1 and his name is:store1.

to get all store by websites:

```
$websiteId=1;
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteId); 
foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            echo $store->getId() ." ".$store->getName()."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Someone knows how to do it with a collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of all the stores and there you can apply your filters.
For example:

```
// In this example, select all the stores  with ID != 1 and Name != 'Dutch'
$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('neq' => 1)) 
                ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('neq' => 'Dutch'));

foreach ($stores as $store) {
    echo $store->getId() . " " . $store->getName() . "<br/>";
}
```